# Disable button in FormBuilder Angular 4

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I use FormBuilder in Angular 4 and i need to disable submit button, when not filled all the fields.

**component.ts**

```
public loginForm = this.fb.group({
email: ['', Validators.required],
password: ['', Validators.required],});

constructor(
public fb: FormBuilder
) {  }
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin($event)">
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
    <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

And now button is active, that is not right

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use disabled property with checking form validation state

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin($event)">
    <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly say it :

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Log in</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin($event)">
  <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
  <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid || loginForm.pristine">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to give some context with your answer. Explain your solution a bit.